# How can I assign minus 1/yesterday from today SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am confused date on SAS.

For example

```
%let fdate = %sysfunc(today(),EURDFDE9.);
```

shows 18JUN2019

How about I would like to show yesterday like 17JUN2019

I try to -1 but it did not work,how can I code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the result of `%sysfunc(today(),EURDFDE9.)` is the **string** `18JUN2019`. You can't subtract 1 from this. However, today() is a numeric value, so if you store this value instead, you can subtract 1 subsequently. Note that macro variables are stored as string, so even if fdate is a numeric string, you need %eval to do the subtraction.

```
%let fdate=%sysfunc(today());
%put %sysfunc(putn(&fdate,EURDFDE9.));
%let ydate=%eval(&fdate-1);
%put %sysfunc(putn(&ydate,EURDFDE9.));
```